# Comparing two columns across tables for a remaining subset

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I find the unique phone numbers (and collapse them into a single column) from table_1 (while keeping the IDs and date fields), and remove phone numbers that appear in table_2?

### table_1

| id | phone1 | phone2 | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1111111111 |  | 2021-12-31 |
| 5 | 2222222222 | 3333333333 | 2020-11-08 |
| 8 | 5555555555 |  | 2021-03-15 |
| 14 | 7777777777 | 8888888888 | 2016-10-20 |

### table_2

| id | phone1 | phone2 | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 567 | 4444444444 | 1111111111 | 2020-11-28 |
| 660 | 8888888888 |  | 2018-01-01 |
| 898 | 9999999999 |  | 2017-04-06 |

regardless of which phone column the phone appears in, I want to remove it from the end results. so ID 1 with phone of 1111111111 would be removed because it is in phone2 on Table 2

### Desired output

| id | phone_num | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2222222222 | 2020-11-08 |
| 5 | 3333333333 | 2020-11-08 |
| 8 | 5555555555 | 2021-03-15 |
| 14 | 7777777777 | 2016-10-20 |

What I have so far, which seems to work, is this. I feel like there has to be a more efficient way to do this though.

````
select * from (
    select id, phone1 as phone_num, date from table_1
    union all
    select id, phone2 as phone_num, date from table_1
) tmp

where phone_num not in (
    select phone1 as phone_num from table_2
    union all
    select phone2 as phone_num from table_2
)

order by id desc;
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to avoid hitting table 2 twice:

```
select tmp.* from (
    select id, phone1 as phone_num, date from table_1
    union all
    select id, phone2 as phone_num, date from table_1
) tmp
left join table_2 t2 on phone_num in (t2.phone1, t2.phone2)
where t2.id is null
```